# Как поменять сортировку прямым выбором так, чтобы сортировались только положительные элементы? python

Tags: python

Как поменять сортировку прямым выбором так, чтобы сортировались только положительные элементы, а отрицательные оставались на местах? Пробовал множество условий, но все равно меняются местами отрицательные элементы.

```
def selectionSort(arr)
    size = len(arr) 
    for i in range(0, size-1):
        min = i
        for j in range(i+1, size):
            if arr[j] < arr[min]:
                min = j
        temp = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[min]
        arr[min] = temp
```

Comment: Покажите хоть какие-то варианты вашего *"множество условий"*

Comment: А зачем они нужны, если они вообще не работают...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два маленьких изменения позволяют игнорировать отрицательные элементы:

```
def selectionSort(arr):
    size = len(arr)
    for i in range(0, size-1):
        if a[i] < 0:     #######
            continue
        min = i
        for j in range(i+1, size):
            if arr[j] >=0 and arr[j] < arr[min]:    #######
                min = j
        temp = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[min]
        arr[min] = temp

a = [-3, 5, 2, -4, 8, -3, 1, 4]
selectionSort(a)
print(a)

>>  [-3, 1, 2, -4, 4, -3, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Выдвину идею.
Во второй список вынести положительные элементы.
Отсортировать второй список.
Перезаписать положительные элементы исходного списка элементами второго списка.

```
def selectionSort(arr):
    b = []
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] >= 0:
            b.append(arr[i])
    print(b)        
    b.sort()
    k = 0        
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] >= 0:
            arr[i] = b[k]
            k += 1

a = [-3, 5, 2, -4, 8, -3, 1, 4]
selectionSort(a)
print(a)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).